# Usar a câmera para medir a altura de parte do corpo

Tags: android, processamento-de-imagens, android-camera

Estou projetando um aplicativo que vai medir partes do corpo pra ver qual acessório se encaixa melhor. Eu gostaria de saber se a câmera de um Smartphone tem essa capacidade e como instanciar isso no projeto

Comment: Para medir uma altura seria necessário uma escala para comparar , em que condições seria esta medida ?

Comment: seria em centimetros

Comment: a escala é o de menos, o problema seria saber o que é pra comparar

Comment: Possível é, mas o problema principal no meu ponto de vista é a forma como ele vai ser utilizado, ou seja, se ele bater a foto do braço de frente, é uma medida, se bater de cima pra baixo, outra medida..

Sem contar que cada camera trata profundidade e abertura de lente diferente, o que também pode gerar resultados diferentes..

Comment: isso poderia ser resolvido com uma instrução de como ele deve tirar a foto

Comment: a tecnologia dos smartphones nn chegou a esse nível sinto te informar

Comment: Actualmente so o projecto Tango da Google consegue fazer medidas e que eu saiba ainda so existe dois telemoveis no mercado com essa capacidade
Mais informaçoes: https://get.google.com/tango/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvgPrZNp4So

Comment: Resposta: sim, é possível. Te ajudou? Não né? Não ajudou porque, embora seja uma resposta válida pra sua pergunta, ela é ampla e genérica (exatamente da forma como a sua pergunta está). Você vai notar que eu coloquei a tag [tag:processamento-de-imagens], e a razão é que é possível fazer isso que você quer processando imagens capturadas pela câmera. Mas isso é complexo e envolve algumas tarefas: 1) identificar e separar a parte do corpo (ou a pessoa toda); 2) estimar o tamanho e altura desse "objeto" separado.

Comment: As duas tarefas têm suas complexidades. Sugiro que você dê uma estudada em mais detalhes nesses assuntos e depois poste uma pergunta mais objetiva (por exemplo, como segmentar uma pessoa em uma imagem). Vai ser útil dar uma olhada nas perguntas que já existem na tag por aqui, e estudar um pouco de [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) (a biblioteca mais popular pra te ajudar a fazer o que precisa).